# XPATH - rutas erróneas

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ies>
    <nombre>Mi IES favorito</nombre>
    <web>http://www.mi-IES.org</web>
    <ciclos>
        <ciclo id="ASIR">
            <nombre>Administración de Sistemas Informáticos en Red</nombre>
            <grado>Superior</grado>
            <decretoTitulo año="2009" />
        </ciclo>
        <ciclo id="DAW">
            <nombre>Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web</nombre>
            <grado>Superior</grado>
            <decretoTitulo año="2010" />
        </ciclo>
        <ciclo id="SMR">
            <nombre>Sistemas Microinformáticos y Redes</nombre>
            <grado>Medio</grado>
            <decretoTitulo año="2008" />
            </ciclo>
        </ciclos>
    <modulos>
        <modulo id="0228">
            <nombre>Aplicaciones web</nombre>
            <curso>2</curso>
            <horasSemanales>4</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>SMR</ciclo>
        </modulo>
        <modulo id="0372">
            <nombre>Gestión de bases de datos</nombre>
            <curso>1</curso>
            <horasSemanales>5</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>ASIR</ciclo>
        </modulo>
        <modulo id="0373">
            <nombre>Lenguajes de marcas y sistemas de gestión de información</nombre>
            <curso>1</curso>
            <horasSemanales>3</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>ASIR</ciclo>
            <ciclo>DAW</ciclo>
        </modulo>
        <modulo id="0376">
            <nombre>Implantación de aplicaciones web</nombre>
            <curso>2</curso>
            <horasSemanales>5</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>ASIR</ciclo>
        </modulo>
    </modulos>
</ies>
```

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema con dos rutas de XPATH, quiero extraer de este documento XML lo correspondiente al nombre de los ciclos que incluyen el módulo "Lenguajes de marcas y sistemas de gestión de información" y el nombre de los módulos de ciclos de Grado Superior, sin embargo no logro dar con la ruta acertada y he probado varias maneras, de las cuales han sido erróneas, pues o bien no me agarraba la parte del código que quería o simplemente no lo detectaba.

Se supone que para el primer caso debería extraerme:
Administración de Sistemas Informáticos en Red
Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web

Y para el segundo:
Gestión de bases de datos
Lenguajes de marcas y sistemas de gestión de información
Implantación de aplicaciones web

Comment: por favor muéstraños qué expresiones has probado. En qué lenguaje estás ejecutando esto?

Comment: Listo, ya lo he solucionado, muchas gracias por tu interes.

Comment: Cuéntanos cómo lo solucionaste. Otro visitante puede llegar buscando solucionar un problema parecido

Comment: Listo, ya añadi la respuesta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he logrado averiguarlo, para obtener "Lenguajes de marcas y sistemas de gestión de información", se puede sacar con la ruta:

```
 //ciclo[@id=//modulo[nombre="Lenguajes de marcas y sistemas de gestión de información"]/ciclo]/nombre/text()
```

Y para obtener el nombre de los módulos de ciclos de Grado Superior, se puede sacar con esta siguiente ruta:

```
 //modulo[ciclo=//ciclo[grado="Superior"]/@id]/nombre/text()
```